# Ajax attached to click event not getting spied using sinon

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, sinon

I have some js for which I want to write unit test cases using sinon. My js looks like following

```
var succesHandler = function() {
   console.log("yeah success");
};

var failureHandler = function() {
   console.log("oops error");
};

var ajaxCall = function(payload, successHandler, failureHandler) {
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/myUrl",
    contentType: 'application/json',
    data: JSON.stringify(payload),
    success: successHandler,
    error: failureHandler
});
};

$('#my-button').live('click', function() {
  var dummyPayload = {
   "hello" : "coder"
};  
  ajaxCall(dummyPayload, successHandler, failureHandler);
});

return {
 ajaxCall: ajaxCall,
 successHandler: successHandler,
 failureHandler: failureHandler
};
```

I want to know how do I spy the `ajaxCall()` method attached to the ***#my-button*** click? Also, how to spy `successHandler` and `failureHandler`

Comment: Your code has syntax error. Please edit.

Comment: @slideshowp2 can you enlighten me how it has wrong syntax?

Comment: 1. There is no `errorHandler` 2. You can't use `return` statement in a module(file) directly. Your code is not completed.

Comment: `live()` ? What ancient version of jQuery are you using? It was removed from jQuery in 1.9 which is from January 2013.